# JS select nth member of class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few `<div>`s on my page like so:

```
        <div class="countSections"></div>
        <div class="countSections"></div>
        <div class="countSections"></div>
        <div class="countSections"></div>
        <div class="countSections"></div>
        <div class="countSections"></div>
```

I also have a JS variable:

```
var score = 0;
```

I would like to, using JavaScript (not JQuery), select the nth member of the  class **countSections** to do some CSS styling.

The **nth** value will be the variable `score`'s value. So if `score = 10`then I would like to select the 10th member of the class **countSections**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you can just pass the `score` as your index. Keep in mind that you'll also want to subtract 1, remembering that arrays start at 0:

```js
let score = 3;
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('countSections')[score - 1];
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="countSections">1</div>
<div class="countSections">2</div>
<div class="countSections">3</div>
<div class="countSections">4</div>
<div class="countSections">5</div>
<div class="countSections">6</div>
```

Comment: This is a bad answer.

Comment: @Geuis why is that? What do you think would be a better answer?

Comment: @Geuis - Can you please explain why `:nth-child` is a better answer? As far as I'm aware, my approach directly solves the problem at hand (so IMO is certainly not worthy of your down-vote). If there's an issue that I've overlooked, I'd love to know about it (so I can improve my future answers). Simply stating that the answer is bad doesn't really give me much to work on, but I'm happy to improve this answer :)

Comment: You don’t need to use specialized methods and array indexes. You should just use querySelector when expecting one node or querySelectorAll when querying the DOM for all matches. Combine with the appropriate CSS selector and that’s all you need. Keep it simple.

Comment: Obsidian Age  Just clearing up.. if I did.. var x = document.getElementsByClassName('countSections')   would x.length then return the number of members within the countSection class?

Answer (score 2):

Use css selectors:

```js
const score = 3;
const selection = document.querySelector(`.countSections:nth-child(${score})`);
```

```html
<div class="countSections">1</div>
<div class="countSections">2</div>
<div class="countSections">3</div>
<div class="countSections">4</div>
<div class="countSections">5</div>
<div class="countSections">6</div>
```

Comment: For the reader, note the backticks in the querySelector. Its a template, with parameter score.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can use ':nth-child' selector. From [CSS-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/):

> The :nth-child selector allows you to select one or more elements based on their source order, according to a formula.

Here is an example:

```js
let score = 3;
const element = document.querySelector('.countSections:nth-child('+score+')')
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="countSections">1</div>
<div class="countSections">2</div>
<div class="countSections">3</div>
<div class="countSections">4</div>
<div class="countSections">5</div>
<div class="countSections">6</div>
```

Comment: You just copied my answer =/

Comment: @Geuis Nope. I spent a little bit more time to put link to documentation